# Approximate an integral with Bessel functions

Tags: integration, asymptotics, approximation, bessel-functions

Given $r,a,\lambda\in\mathbb{R}$, $r<a$, how can I find an approximate solution for the following definite integral?

$$
\int_0^\infty J_0 (\lambda r)J_1(\lambda a)\frac{1}{\sqrt{n+\lambda^2 }}\,d\lambda 
$$

$J_0,J_1$ are Bessel function of first kind, $0$th and $1$st order, respectively. $n$ is an imaginary parameter ($i\omega/\alpha$ where $\omega$ is angular frequency and $\alpha$ is thermal diffusivity) and cannot be considered small. $\lambda$ is the Fourier transform variable, $r$ is the radial coordinate and $a$ is a constant and can be considered small.

Comment: I would be glad to provide an answer, but I am paralyzed at the moment. It happens every time I see an integral with a completely useless extra parameter ($n$).

Comment: In additon to @JackD'Aurizio remark, would u be so nice to tell us something about the other parameters? tend they to infinity or zero? how big are they compared to each other?

Comment: For $n=0$ we have $\dfrac2\pi~E\bigg(\dfrac ra\bigg)$, see [elliptic integrals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elliptic_integral) for more information.

Comment: $n$ is an imaginary parameter ($i\omega/\alpha$ where $\omega$  is angular frequency  and $\alpha$ is thermal diffusivity) and cannot be considered small. $\lambda$ is the Fourier transform variable, $r$ is the radial coordinate and $a$ is a constant and can be considered small.

Comment: Yes, but even so, it may be profitable to consider limits of $n$ both small and large.  In that way, something like a two-point Pade approximant may be constructed.